# Convert .car file PBC to basis vectors?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I have a `.car` file that contains dimensions (periodic boundary conditions) for the unit-cell of a hexagonal crystal material I'm working with:

`PBC   27.1979   27.1979   15.4999   90.0000   90.0000  120.0000 (P1)`

That's the a, b, c lengths and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ angles.

I need to convert this information into basis vectors in cartesian space, e.g.

`basis1 27.1979 ?       0.0
 basis2 0.0     27.1979 0.0
 basis3 0.0     0.0     15.4999`

This may be better suited as a math question but it's computational-chemistry specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the way to convert the hexagonal parameters:

I have a,b,c and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. The solution in basis vectors is:

```
basis1 = (a, 0, 0)
basis2 = (xy, yx, 0)
basis3 = (xz, yz, c)
```

where
\begin{align}
xy &= b\cdot\cos(\gamma)\\
yx &= b\cdot\sin(\gamma)\\
xz &= c\cdot\cos(\beta)\\
yz &= \frac{b\cdot c\cdot \cos(\alpha) - xy \cdot xz}{\sqrt{b^2 - xy^2}}\\
\end{align}

Thus my solution was:

```
basis1 = (27.1979,  0,       0     )
basis2 = (-13.5990, 23.5541, 0     )
basis3 = (0,        0,       15.499)
```

Comment: Since $\alpha=\beta=90^\circ$, you may simplify this a great deal. Your third vector is just $(0,0,c)$.